# How to Export Jquery Flot Line Chart as an Image or PDF?

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

How can i Export the **Jquery Flot Line Chart** including the Axis and title.
but i want to export it using JavaScript and i am filling up the chart using API Link.

Below is the Image of the Chart.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a button with id="save", then try this plug-in with the code below

```js
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('section.panel')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('graph.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Photo Statistics 2015 
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="flot-1ine2" style="height:275px"></div>
    </div>
</section>
<button onclick="demoFromHTML()">Save as PDF</button>
```

**EDIT: Or if png is acceptable:**

```js
html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        // AJAX call to send `data` to a PHP file that creates an image from the dataURI string and saves it to a directory on the server

        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
    }
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
    <section class="panel panel-default">
        <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Photo Statistics 2015 
        </header>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="flot-1ine2" style="height:275px"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<br>
<br>
    
<div id="canvas">
    <p>Canvas:</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="image">
        <p>Image:</p>
    </div>
<script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: I forgot, add this up top: <script src="https://raw.github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>

Comment: <section class="panel panel-default">
   <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Photo Statistics 2015
      <span id="save"> Download</span>
  </header>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="flot-1ine2" style="height:275px"></div>
</div>
</section>

This is my code where i displaying the Chart.

Comment: i try to use this one as well :


$( "#download" ).click(function() {
                      Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(document.getElementById('flot-1ine2'));
                 });

Comment: it is saving as PDF but it is not taking the Contents of DIV which have The Chart ?  

where we need to pass the Div ID?? because <section> tag i am using at so many places on this page.

Comment: i replace the $('section.panel') with $('#flot-1ine2') but now it is only capturing the X-Axis and Y-Axis Values only not the Chart ??? how can we  can capture the DIV content as image (PNG,JPEG etc) or PDF ???

Comment: I am curious, is there any <canvas> tags in your graph html?

Comment: Hi,
 your code for show in PNG is working. Now my Question is rather than showing the Image in the DIV Tag, i want to ask user the Location. So user can save where ever he want. How can i implement this feature ?